# How to bootstrap installation of Python modules on Amazon EMR?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

I want to do something really basic, simply fire up a Spark cluster through the EMR console and run a Spark script that depends on a Python package (for example, [Arrow](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow)). What is the most straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to create a bash script containing your installation commands, copy it to S3, and set a bootstrap action from the console to point to your script.

Here's an example I'm using in production:

> s3://mybucket/bootstrap/install_python_modules.sh

```
#!/bin/bash -xe

# Non-standard and non-Amazon Machine Image Python modules:
sudo pip install -U \
  awscli            \
  boto              \
  ciso8601          \
  ujson             \
  workalendar

sudo yum install -y python-psycopg2
```

Comment: this will install the packages on one of the nodes in the EMR cluster. How can I make sure the package gets installed on all nodes?

Comment: This installs the packages on all of the nodes

Comment: This is not working for Python3. I'm trying to install Pandas. Any new suggestions?

Comment: @EvanZamir check my answer, you need to use pip-3.4 in the script instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/51210608/3424322

Comment: This does not follow typical conventions of using a requirements.txt for containing requirements.  In order to allow for local and remote execution, you should use `aws s3 cp` to copy a requirements.txt to a local folder, then install using `pip install -y requirements.txt` after you have copied the requirements file from s3.

Comment: @noli is there a reason to use yum over pip for one portion of your code above?

Comment: @jwx . I don't remember tbh, but I wonder if it was due to some packaging issues on the EMR image, when I first wrote the script (5 yrs ago)

Answer (score 11):

In short, there are two ways to install packages with pip, depending on the platform. First, you install whatever you need and then you can run your Spark step. The easiest is to use emr-4.0.0 and 'command-runner.jar':

```
from boto.emr.step import JarStep
>>> pip_step=JarStep(name="Command Runner",
...             jar="command-runner.jar",
...             action_on_failure="CONTINUE",
...             step_args=['sudo','pip','install','arrow']
... )
>>> spark_step=JarStep(name="Spark with Command Runner",
...                    jar="command-runner.jar",
...                    step_args=["spark-submit","/usr/lib/spark/examples/src/main/python/pi.py"]
...                    action_on_failure="CONTINUE"
)
>>> step_list=conn.add_jobflow_steps(emr.jobflowid, [pip_step,spark_step])
```

On 2.x and 3.x, you use script-runner.jar in a similar fashion except that you have to specify the full URI for [scriptrunner](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html).

EDIT:
Sorry, I didn't see that you wanted to do this through console. You can add the same steps in the console as well. The first step would be a Customer JAR with the same args as above. The second step is a spark step. Hope this helps!

Comment: where does `conn` come from

Comment: I wonder why they removed the `JarStep` from `boto3`, It looks so much cleaner than having a dictionary with the same arguments...

Answer (score 9):

Depending if you are using Python 2 (default in EMR) or Python 3, the pip install command should be different. 
As recommended in [noli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31792868/3424322), you should create a shell script, upload it to a bucket in S3, and use it as a [Bootstrap action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html).

For Python 2 (in Jupyter: used as default for pyspark kernel):

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
sudo pip install your_package
```

For Python 3 (in Jupyter: used as default for Python 3 and **pyspark3** kernel):

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
sudo pip-3.4 install your_package
```

Comment: This works fine if you are using a specific EMR that uses python 3.4.  This needs to be examined separately for each EMR version.  For instance, `emr-5.21.0` uses `python-3.6`, thus you need to adjust pip to `pip-3.6`, so this is not a one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: Another note is that if you are wanting to get rid of the entire stderr log when using both versions of pip to install, the following will help in your bootstrap action shell script:  `sudo sed -i -e 's/$OLD_PIP_VERSION/$PIP_VERSION/g' /usr/bin/pip-3.6`, based upon the version specified

Comment: Would `sudo pip3 install..` circumvent the version tagging issue?

Comment: ```#! /bin/bash -xe  ;
sudo pip-3.6 install boto3``` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This post got me started down the right path but ultimately I ended on a different solution.

`boostrap.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sudo python3 -m pip install \
    botocore \
    boto3 \
    ujson \
    warcio \
    beautifulsoup4  \
    lxml
```

`create_emr_cluster.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

pem_file="~/.ssh/<your pem file>.pem"
bootstrap_path="s3://<path without filename>/"
subnet_id="subnet-<uniuqe subnet id>"
logs_path="s3://<log directory (optional)>/elasticmapreduce/"

aws s3 cp ./bootstrap.sh $bootstrap_path

ID=$(aws emr create-cluster \
--name spark-data-processing \
--use-default-roles \
--release-label emr-5.30.1 \
--instance-count 2 \
--application Name=Spark Name=Hive Name=Ganglia Name=Zeppelin \
--ec2-attributes KeyName=<your pem file>,SubnetId=$subnet_id \
--instance-type m4.large \
--bootstrap-actions Path=${bootstrap_path}bootstrap.sh \
--query ClusterId \
--output text \
--log-uri ${logs_path})
```

[credit to](https://github.com/EricRops) for his help

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3 - create a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
sudo pip3 install your_package
```

Copy it to S3, and set a bootstrap action from the console to point to your script.