# External dependency for spark job

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I am new to big data technologies.I have to run a spark job in cluster mode on EMR. The job is written in python and it has dependencies on several libraries and some other tools. I have already written the script and run it in local client mode.But it arising some dependency issue when I am trying to run it using yarn.How do I manage these dependencies?

Log :

```
"/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1511680510570_0144/container_1511680510570_0144_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 711, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ImportError: ('No module named boto3', <function subimport at 0x7f8c3c4f9c80>, ('boto3',))

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Could you provide the errors messages here?

Comment: I have added the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have not installed Boto 3 library.
Download the compatible one and install it using below

```
$ pip install boto3
```

or `python -m pip install --user boto3`

Hope this helps.You can refer the link-`https://github.com/boto/boto3`

Then it seems you have not installed the boot 3 on all executors(nodes). Since, you are running spark, python code is running partly on driver and executors.You need to install the library in all nodes if its **yarn**.

To install the same.Please refer-[How to bootstrap installation of Python modules on Amazon EMR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525012/how-to-bootstrap-installation-of-python-modules-on-amazon-emr)

Comment: I have installed the boto3 and run the job in local client mode using. It was working fine. I am facing this problem while using it with yarn.

Comment: Did  boto3 installation on all nodes worked for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have solved the issue. Is there any way to add bootstrap action on a running cluster using cli ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can-

`aws emr create-cluster --bootstrap-actions Path=<>,Name=BootstrapAction1,Args=[arg1,arg2].. --auto-terminate`.Please refer below-http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html#bootstrapUses