# AWS EMR install python libraries

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, emr

I am running a Map Reduce Code in Amazon EMR using Python which uses the native boto library. I need to know which packages are pre-installed in the cluster nodes ? Also how do I automatically install some modules while bootstrapping ?

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525012/how-to-bootstrap-installation-of-python-modules-on-amazon-emr

Comment: If you are using Python 3, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51210608/3424322

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bootstrap installation of Python modules on Amazon EMR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525012/how-to-bootstrap-installation-of-python-modules-on-amazon-emr)