# Deploying pyspark CommonCrawl repo to EMR

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, common-crawl

I'm trying to extract WET files from the public CommonCrawl data hosted on S3 from my EMR cluster. To do this, CommonCrawl has a [cc-pyspark repo](https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-pyspark#running-in-spark-cluster-over-large-amounts-of-data) where they provide examples and instructions, however, I don't understand the instructions to get things going. **How do I deploy this repo to my cluster?** Should this be a part of my bootstrap script?

The end goal is to process the text in the WET files via a spark job. So far I've been using the hosted notebooks to try and download WET files with boto3, with no success.

[Here is the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525012/how-to-bootstrap-installation-of-python-modules-on-amazon-emr/64093831#64093831) I used to bootstrap EMR with the additional python packages.

Comment: does your bootstrap script install all the dependencies? `pip install -r requirements.txt` will not work as a bootstrap action. You need to copy the requirements file, or explicitly install the dependencies (they are not that many, i just opened the file).

Comment: Yes, I believe I captured all the dependencies of that repo in my bootstrap script.

Comment: The cc-pyspark project was developed  to be run via command-line without the need to install cc-pyspark beforehand in the cluster. Just run one a script and "deploy" sparkcc.py via --py-files: `spark-submit --py-files sparkcc.py word_count.py`. I haven't ever tried to run it from a notebook - some modifications or work-arounds are likely required, mostly because cc-pyspark relies on argparse.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect you to respond to this personally. Thank you so much! I only discovered CommonCrawl recently and find it fascinating. I'll give your suggestion a try. Thanks again!