# Capture Master public DNS when creating cluster via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, command-line-interface, aws-cli

Is there a way to capture the `master public DNS` of an AWS EMR cluster after it's been created via CLI? I'm using [these scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64093831/14343465) to accomplish this.

A second question, that may be outside SO guidelines, what are best practices for capturing variables from the command line and then editing a bash script? I've considered environmental variables but my understanding is that custom variables don't persist beyond the shell session.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For capturing EMR master public DNS:

- Wait for the cluster to be in running state:
- `aws emr wait cluster-running --cluster-id $ID`
- Describe the cluster and get the master public DNS name:
- `MASTER_DNS=$(aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id $ID --query 'Cluster.MasterPublicDnsName' --output text)`

You may pass environment variables from one script to the other or use some external storage. [More details on sharing variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9772093/9907481)